# Disable PHP in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm working on an android app where I want a webpage to be view-able but nothing to be clickable. I've successfully disabled the JavaScript and the URLs but there is a button that has functionality in PHP. Is there a way to specifically disable that as well? I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: `there is a button that has functionality in PHP. `. Please show how that looks like. Source code please.

Answer (score 1):

> set "onTouchListener" to the webview, disable the click over there.